# Change customer account create email template magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

When a customer is registered a email is sent to customer.I want to set the styling of that templates.When i navigate from admin dashboard to Marketing->Email Templates.There are only two email templates for new order pickup order and new pickup order for guest.Where is the customer account email template?How i style that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overwrite below customer account creation email template file in your theme:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/account_new.html

You can write your own html and style code in this template file.

Hope this help you. If you have any further query please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: How can i style them?

Comment: Either you can write your style code inline if there are not much css code to include. Or you can create a separate css or less file at this directory "app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/custom.css" to write your custom css.